# merge the list data based on rownames in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, data-management

I'm trying to merge the data in a list, but I found their lengths are not exactly the same. Some has length 65 while some has 66.

[image]

`datalist_BAL` is my list of the data and `datalist_BAL_name` is the name of the list. I tried to create another list `BAL` with the rowname and merge together based on the rowname into `BAL_data`. Below is my code.

```
BAL <-list()
BAL_data<-data.frame()
    
for(i in 1:length(datalist_BAL)){
dt<- t(datalist_BAL[[i]])
rownames(dt)<-t(datalist_BAL_name[[i]])
BAL[[i]] <- dt
if (i==1) {next()}
BAL_data<-merge(BAL[[i-1]],BAL[[i]],by = "row.names",all= TRUE)

}
```

I generated `BAL_data` successfully but it only contains two columns.

[image]

So I wonder how I can run a loop to merge all the data of the list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I would do it. I think the problem was that you were ony using 2 dataframe to merge, this is why you only had two columns. You might also consider changing the column names.

```
datalist_BAL <- list(data.table(text=c('a', 'b'), merge_col=c('1', '2')), 
data.table(text=c('c', 'd'), merge_col=c('1', '2')),
                 data.table(text=c('e', 'f'), merge_col=c('1', '2')))


BAL <-list()
BAL_data<-data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(datalist_BAL)){
  dt<- datalist_BAL[[i]]
  if (i==1) {
  BAL_data <- dt
next()}
BAL_data<-merge(BAL_data,dt,by = "merge_col",all= TRUE)

}
```

This means that your code will change like this

```
BAL <-list()
BAL_data<-data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(datalist_BAL)){
dt<- t(datalist_BAL[[i]])
rownames(dt)<-t(datalist_BAL_name[[i]])
BAL[[i]] <- dt
if (i==1) {
BAL_data <- dt
next()}
BAL_data<-merge(BAL_data,BAL[[i]],by = "row.names",all= TRUE)

}
```